# Dirichlet Test For Convergence Of Improper Integrals

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $f(x), g(x)$ are defined on $[a, \infty)$ such that $f(x)$ is decreasing and $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$$ and $g(x)$ is continuous in its domain and the integral satisfies $$\int_a^xg(t)\,dt<M$$ for every $x$ in the above given interval, then prove that $$\int_a^xf(t)g(t)\,dt$$ converges.
$$$$I tried the generalized mean value theorem but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See: [ask] a good question

Comment: Proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2752694/148510) along with Abel's test. You need the Second Mean Value Theorem for integrals.