# Does $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} e^{-\alpha x}dx$ converge uniformly?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

> Does $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} e^{-\alpha x}dx \hspace{0.1cm}, \alpha \in ]0,\infty[$$ converge uniformly?

Using the **Dirichlet test**:

1. $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = \pi/2$
2. $e^{-\alpha x}$ is decreasing, bounded and going to $0$.

So it converges uniformly.

Is this ok? Or does it only converge uniformly in $]k,\infty[$ with $k>0$ ?

Comment: Which formulation(s) of Dirichlet's test do you know? Does any of them say that 1. and 2. imply uniform convergence? If yes, then it's obviously okay. If not, then you still need to show it.

Comment: I think he only can conclude that the improper integral converge: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141048/798113

Comment: @Ramanujan: There is a version of the Dirichlet test that gives uniform convergence.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519281/if-int-0-infty-fx-dx-converges-will-int-0-inftye-sx-fx)

Comment: Now I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint to use the Dirichlet test:

We have $\int_0^c \sin x \, dx$ bounded for all $c > 0$ and independent of $\alpha$ and $\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x}$ is monotonically decreasing in $x$ and **uniformly convergent** to $0$ as $x \to \infty$ for all $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks again! This subject is really hard for me because I don't think I have the best definitions of criteria and I get confused, and I can't find anything on this on Wikipedia( unbelievable!). I just find theory on the criteria of series, and I have to guess and adapt to integrals. For instance, the criteria I have for the Dirichlet test didn't say that that the function needed to converge uniformly to 0, just that it converges to 0. If you have a pdf or something on this, I appreciate it. I will probably still struggle a little bit, but at least I'll know I'm using the right criteria.

Comment: .--  and most books now don't really cover this topic well. However The Elements of Real Analysis by Bartle (earlier editions like 2nd) has a good section on improper integrals with a parameter.

Comment: @PedroFernandes: Actually [this](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_IMPROPER_FUNCTIONS.PDF) is very good.

Comment: Thank you for the book reference and the link. One question, $|f_{n}(x)|=|\frac{e^{-n x}}{x}|$ doesn't have a supremum right? So why is it uniformly convergent?

Comment: For $\alpha,x \geqslant 0$ we have $0 \leqslant e^{-\alpha x} \leqslant 1$.  Thus, $\left|\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x} \right| = \frac{|e^{-\alpha x}|}{x} \leqslant \frac{1}{x}$.  The RHS converges to $0$ and does not depend on $\alpha$. Hence, we have uniform convergence.

Comment: I realize now that you can prove uniform convergence as you did because of Abel's test.  This says  that $\int_0^\infty f(x, \alpha) g(x, \alpha) \, dx$ converges uniformly for $\alpha \in D$ if $\int_0^\infty f(x,\alpha) \, dx$ is uniformly convergent and $g$ is monotone (increasing or decreasing) and uniformly bounded for all $x$ and $\alpha \in D$.  You have that here with $f(x,\alpha) = \sin x/x$ and $g(x,\alpha) = e^{-\alpha x}$

Comment: I'm confused. I thought we had to take the limit of $\alpha$.

Comment: No we care that $\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x} \searrow 0$ as $x \to \infty$ uniformly for $\alpha \in D$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2752694/148510) is a proof of both tests without the uniform part. They are closely related and the discussion of Abel's test for uniform convergence of an improper integral is even harder to find.

Comment: Clearly $|e^{-\alpha x}| \leqslant 1$ so it is uniformly bounded for all $x, \alpha \geqslant 0$.  Also $e^{-\alpha x_2} \leqslant e^{-\alpha x_1}$ for all $\alpha \geqslant 0$ when $x_2 > x_1 \geqslant 0$. Also $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx$ converges (uniformly) since there is no dependence on $\alpha$ and Abel's test applies.  So this can be proved with either test.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience! I get that the abel test works now, I was forgetting uniform convergence only applies on integrals/series/functions with parameters, so now that I understand that it becomes clear in my mind. At first, I thought of Abel's test but I was thinking 'is sin(x)/x uniformly convergent?'. Still the Dirichlet test justification is bugging me. Because uniform convergence means that given an $\epsilon>0$ we can take an $n>N$ such that $|f_{n}(x)| < \epsilon \forall x>0$ or am I missing something? Can I get such $N$ ?

Comment: We can take any N that's it? Because  $n>N \implies \frac{e^{-nx}}{x}<\frac{e^{-Nx}}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x} < \epsilon$  is that it?

Comment: No we need that there exists $X_0 > 0$ independent of $\alpha$ such that for all $x > X_0$ we have $\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x} < \epsilon$ for ALL $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$.  I think you are confusing this Dirichlet test for uniform convergence of an improper integral with some question of when you can take a limit with respect to $n \to \infty$ under an integral $\int_0^\infty f_n(x) \, dx$.

Comment: I think I may be talking about something else? I was thinking of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence because now we are talking about uniform convergence of a function, and not of an integral or series right? What am I confusing?

Comment: It's because $\alpha$ is not discrete right?

Comment: I think I never saw a definition of uniform convergence of a function with a continuous parameter, is that what I am confused with?

Comment: To be clear you are asking first and foremost about the uniform convergence of an improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x,\alpha) g(x, \alpha) \, dx$ for $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$.  That means you want to know if $\int_0^b  f(x,\alpha) g(x, \alpha) \, dx \to \int_0^\infty f(x,\alpha) g(x, \alpha) \, dx$ as $b \to \infty$ UNIFORMLY for $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$.  The Dirichlet test can be applied if along with the other hypothesis we have $g(x,\alpha) \searrow 0$ as $x \to \infty$ uniformly for all $\alpha \in [0,\alpha)$.  It is important that we consider this limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: We dont care about the limit as $\alpha \to \infty$ nor is this a question of the uniform convergence of a sequence of functions $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ for $x \in D$.  Now $g(x,\alpha) \to 0$ uniformly as $x \to \infty$ for $\alpha \in [0,\alpha)$ does imply that  $g(n, \alpha) \to 0$ uniformly as $n \to \infty$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) for $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$, but the converse of that is not always true.

Comment: It's clear now! I know exactly what I was confusing, thank you, very enlightening.