# Abel's convergence test proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Let $f,g:[a,\infty] \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t $\int_a^{\infty}f(t)dt$ converges, and $g$ is bounded and monotonic. Then $\int_a^{\infty}f(t)g(t)dt$ converges.

My idea: $g$ is monotonic thus integrable on $[a, x] \forall x$, and $f$ is also integrable, so $f(t)g(t)$ is integrable on $[a, x] \forall x$.

$g$ is monotnic and bounded thus $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x) = L \in \mathbb{R}$, thus there exists $M>0$ s.t $\forall x>M, L-1 \leq g(x) \leq L+1$.

choosing some $b>M$ we get: $\int_b^{x}f(t)(L-1)dt \leq \int_b^{x}f(t)g(t)dt \leq \int_b^{x}f(t)(L+1)dt$

Taking $x \to \infty$, the left and right expressions converge because $\int_b^{\infty}f(t)dt$ converges, thus $\int_b^{\infty}f(t)g(t)dt$ converges.

Also, $\int_a^{b}f(t)g(t)dt$ obviously converges, so we get $\int_a^{\infty}f(t)g(t)dt$ converges.

Other proofs I saw usually used mean-value theorem so I wanna make sure I'm not missing something, thanks

Comment: This does not  prove Abel' s test. You have the problem that $f$ may not be nonnegative and you can't immediately conclude that $(L-1)f(x) \leqslant f(x)g(x) \leqslant (L+1) f(x)$ for all $x$.  Even if your final inequality were true, the best you could get after taking limits is $$(L-1)\int_b^\infty f(t) \, dt \leqslant \liminf_{x \to \infty} \int_b^x f(t) g(t) \, dt \leqslant  \limsup_{x \to \infty} \int_b^x f(t) g(t) \, dt \leqslant (L+1)\int_b^\infty f(t) \, dt,$$

since the far right-hand side and far left-hand sides are unequal.

Comment: The best way in my opinion is to show that the Cauchy criterion is satisfied as given in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2752694/148510).  Proving convergence  in a general setting without  a good guess for the limit usually follows this path.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M = \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)$, as you well said, real M exists since g is bounded and monotonic. Then we can bound your integral as follows:

$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{\infty} f(t)g(t) dt \leq M \displaystyle \int_{a}^{\infty} f(t) dt$

And as the right side integral converges by hyposthesis, you obtained a finite bound, this implies that the left side integral converges too.

Comment: No it doesn't because the functions aren't necessarily positive.

Comment: take a better look, there is no loss of generality when you assume g to be positive

Comment: This is not really helpful.   True that $g$ is eventually nonnegative or nonpositive but what about $f$.  Furthermore you are trying to facilitate an incorrect proof here.